# Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead

Tags: swift, api, codable

I was fetching data from an API returning an array but needed to replace it by an API that has "sub levels":

```
RAW:
    ETH:
        USD:
             TYPE:              "5"
             MARKET:            "CCCAGG"
             FROMSYMBOL:        "ETH"
             TOSYMBOL:          "USD"
             PRICE:             680.89
             CHANGEPCT24HOUR    :   -9.313816893529749
```

Here is my struct:

```
struct Ethereum: Codable {

    let percentChange24h: String
    let priceUSD: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case priceUSD = "PRICE", percentChange24h = "CHANGEPCT24HOUR"
    }
}
```

And the implementation:

```
    func fetchEthereumInfo(completion: @escaping (Ethereum?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            if let ethereumUSD = try JSONDecoder().decode([Ethereum].self, from: data).first {
                print(ethereumUSD)
                completion(ethereumUSD, nil)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

The console prints `typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

I can't really figure out what to update in my code or what this form of API is

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all the JSON does not contain any array. It's very very easy to read JSON. There are only 2 (two!) collection types, array `[]` and dictionary `{}`. As you can see there are no square brackets at all in the JSON string.

Any (sub)dictionary `{}` has to be decoded to its own type, so it's supposed to be

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case raw = "RAW" }
    let raw : RAW
}

struct RAW : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case eth = "ETH" }
    let eth : ETH
}

struct ETH : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case usd = "USD" }
    let usd : USD
}

struct USD : Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case type = "TYPE"
        case market = "MARKET"
        case price = "PRICE"
        case percentChange24h = "CHANGEPCT24HOUR"
    }
    let type : String
    let market : String
    let price : Double
    let percentChange24h : Double
}
```

To decode the JSON and and print `percentChange24h` you have to write

```
 let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
 print("percentChange24h", result.raw.eth.usd.percentChange24h)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vadian! This is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a simpler syntax for `result.raw.eth.usd.percentChange24h` ?

Comment: You could declare a computed variable in `Root` to get `raw.eth.usd`

Comment: Great, by the way I am getting `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Root'` on the `let result` line. I'd like to keep my do-catch method so how can I get rid of the error?

Comment: Don't `if let`, if the decoding succeeds the result is a non-optional

Comment: Don't forget to tell OP to call completion inside the catch and inside the guard else bracket `completion(nil, error)`