# Swift: Check if data response is an array or a dictonary

Tags: json, swift, api, parsing, url

I'm calling an API and storing the data in an array.
But if there is no data the debugger says:
**Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.**

The fail JSON response is:

```
    '{"status":"Failed","msg":"Sorry It\'s Not Working"}'
```

The success JSON response is:

```
'[{"id":"509","name":"TEC TEST !"#!12","sortingId":"1"},
{"id":"510","name":"TEC TEST !"#!12","sortingId":"2"},
{"id":"511","name":"TEC TEST !"#!12","sortingId":"3"},
{"id":"512","name":"TEC TEST !"#!12","sortingId":"4"},
{"id":"513","name":"TEC TEST !"#!12","sortingId":"5"},
{"id":"514","name":"TEC TEST !"#!12","sortingId":"6"},
{"id":"519","name":"TEC TEST !"#!12","sortingId":"7"}]'
```

So I want to switch between fetching my response as

```
var result:[Items]?
```

and

```
var result:Items?
```

if the Failed JSON gets send

I've been google´ing and searching Stackoverflow without luck

Is there an solution to say if JSON is an array or dictionary?

My Struct:

```
struct Items: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let sortingId: String?
    let name: String?
    let response: String?
    let status: String?
    let msg: String?
}
```

My processing of the response:

```
var result:[Items]?
result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Items].self, from: data!)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
for item in result! {
  self.itemArray.append((name: item.name!, id: Int(item.id!)!, sortingId: Int(item.sortingId!)!))
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add an example when the fetch succeeds. The error message is very clear. You are decoding an array `[Items]` but it's actually a dictionary (a single item). That's a good example of the confusion to name a single item in plural form.

Comment: @vadian I've added it now :)

Comment: As it is a string, you could just check if json payload begins wich '[' or '{' to do your prediction.

Comment: Thanks!... But I don't know how to check if the JSON payload contains an [ or not :)

Comment: Is there a change in status code when you get a failure message ? If so you  could probably use that to recognize it as a failure. Generally this is how it should be done, if not done, if the APIs are in your control probably a good idea to change it.

Comment: Yes, the error massage has error code 400, how do I check this in the do{} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to write a custom initializer which conditionally decodes the array or the dictionary.

Please ask the owner of the service to send more consistent JSON. It's very bad. At least the object should be **always** a dictionary with key `status` and either the array for key `items` or the key `msg`.

This code first tries to decode the array with `unkeyedContainer`. If it fails it decodes the dictionary.

```
struct Item: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let sortingId: String
    let name: String
}

struct ItemData : Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case status, msg }

    let status : String?
    let msg: String?
    var items = [Item]()

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        do {
            var unkeyedContainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
            while !unkeyedContainer.isAtEnd {
                items.append(try unkeyedContainer.decode(Item.self))
            }
            status = nil; msg = nil
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            status = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .status)
            msg = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .msg)
        }
    }
}
```

And call it

```
result = try JSONDecoder().decode(ItemData.self, from: data!)
```

---

A – probably more suitable – alternative is to catch the error in the  `JSONDecoder().decode` line and use two simple structs

```
struct Item: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let sortingId: String
    let name: String
}

struct ErrorData : Decodable {
    let status : String
    let msg: String
}
```

and call it

```
do {

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
       let result = try decoder.decode([Item].self, from: data!)
       print(result)
    } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
       let result = try decoder.decode(ErrorData.self, from: data!)
       print(result)
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

A big benefit is that all properties can be non-optional.

Answer (score -2):

First of all the JSON does not contain any array. It's very very easy to read JSON. There are only 2 (two!) collection types, array [] and dictionary {}. As you can see there are no square brackets at all in the JSON string.
   [it will helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007348/expected-to-decode-arrayany-but-found-a-dictionary-instead)

Comment: Thanks! but yes, I know the problem, but I don't know how to check if the JSON contains an array or not as my question is titled :)

Comment: if result count is equal to zero,there is no json data

Comment: check this this is what you are looking for: http://lebedev.cc/swifts-decodable-gotchas/

Comment: Thanks! udaykumar... But there is alway data as the response is either an array of data or a dictionary of data... vadian gave me an answer that solves the problem, look above!.. Im glad you wanted to help! Thanks!!