# Swift 4 JSON decoder with nested data

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsondecoder

This is the data structure (updated):

```
    {
  "date": "2018-10-18",
  "time_of_day": "16:00",
  "request_time": "2018-10-18T16:00:27+01:00",
  "station_name": "London Waterloo",
  "station_code": "WAT",
  "arrivals": {
    "all": [
      {
        "mode": "train",
        "service": "24673605",
        "train_uid": "W12378",
        "platform": "10",
        "operator": "SW",
        "operator_name": "South Western Railway",
        "aimed_departure_time": null,
        "aimed_arrival_time": "05:18",
        "aimed_pass_time": null,
        "origin_name": "Guildford",
        "destination_name": "London Waterloo",
        "source": "ATOC",
        "category": "OO",
        "service_timetable": {
          "id": "https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/service/train_uid:W12378/2018-10-18/timetable.json?app_id=80b56d0a&app_key=b44a5870830959a7a961fdbb65f9dc13"
        }
      },
      {
        "mode": "train",
        "service": "24671505",
        "train_uid": "W14110",
        "platform": "1",
        "operator": "SW",
        "operator_name": "South Western Railway",
        "aimed_departure_time": null,
        "aimed_arrival_time": "05:35",
        "aimed_pass_time": null,
        "origin_name": "Twickenham",
        "destination_name": "London Waterloo",
        "source": "ATOC",
        "category": "OO",
        "service_timetable": {
          "id": "https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/service/train_uid:W14110/2018-10-18/timetable.json?app_id=80b56d0a&app_key=b44a5870830959a7a961fdbb65f9dc13"
        }
      },
      {
        "mode": "train",
        "service": "24671105",
        "train_uid": "W14764",
        "platform": "15",
        "operator": "SW",
        "operator_name": "South Western Railway",
        "aimed_departure_time": null,
        "aimed_arrival_time": "05:41",
        "aimed_pass_time": null,
        "origin_name": "Staines",
        "destination_name": "London Waterloo",
        "source": "ATOC",
        "category": "OO",
        "service_timetable": {
          "id": "https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/service/train_uid:W14764/2018-10-18/timetable.json?app_id=80b56d0a&app_key=b44a5870830959a7a961fdbb65f9dc13"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried the answer here: [Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007348/expected-to-decode-arrayany-but-found-a-dictionary-instead)

But can't quite get it to work. I keep getting and error on this line:

```
let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
```

My models (updated):

```
 struct Root: Decodable {
    let arrivals: Arrivals
}

struct Arrivals: Decodable {
    let all: All
}

struct All: Decodable {
    let trains: [Train]
}
```

Error:

```
▿ DecodingError
  ▿ typeMismatch : 2 elements
    - .0 : Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>
    ▿ .1 : Context
      ▿ codingPath : 2 elements
        - 0 : CodingKeys(stringValue: "arrivals", intValue: nil)
        - 1 : CodingKeys(stringValue: "all", intValue: nil)
      - debugDescription : "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead."
      - underlyingError : nil
```

Comment: Where is the `departures` key equivalent in your `struct` ? It's should be a key of `Root`.

Comment: @matt I didn't show the real JSON because it's very long. I just truncated the end

Comment: Ahh, wrong sample @larme! Apologies. Will update with the right one.

Comment: @matt, yeah sorry mate, got the wrong sample.

Answer (score 2):

> "I've tried the answer here: [Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007348/expected-to-decode-arrayany-but-found-a-dictionary-instead)

Yes, but your error message is just the opposite. Taking a moment to *read* the error message, we can see that it is perfectly clear and obviously right.

In your Arrivals struct, you are saying

```
let all: All
```

But the value of the `"all"` key in the JSON is an array! So the type here must be an array of something. In particular it should be an array of trains.

```
let all: [Train]
```

And now you can delete your All struct, which was never right.

Example (running against the JSON you showed):

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let arrivals: Arrivals
}
struct Arrivals: Decodable {
    let all: [Train]
}
struct Train: Decodable {
}
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
if let root = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data) {
    print("got", String(root.arrivals.all.count), "trains")
}
// "got 3 trains"
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that as well. But that's not what the error is referring to. Let me update with the latest values. The error is saying `arrivals` is `nil`

Comment: However, my answer is absolutely right for the question you asked.

Comment: My answer still seems right to me. Delete your All struct and do what I said.

Comment: Sorry @matt, but it isn't, the parser doesn't even get that far. Look at the error above better formatted.

Comment: It says just what I said. It decodes arrivals but then can’t decode all. You have not done what I said to do so of course it isn’t working.

Comment: Pretty sure Matt is right.  Looking at json, what will you find for value of 'all' key, you find an array of trains.  the key "trains" is not present anywhere in json, yet its your coding key for All struct.

Comment: Added proof that my answer is right, given the JSON provided.