# Error when decoding JSON "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm attempting to get some data from [an API](https://pastebin.com/6tyTa4ui) and when printing the results, I keep running into this error:

`typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "response", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

These are the structs

```
struct Status: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let response: [Response]
}

struct Response: Decodable {
    let docs: [Doc]
}

struct Doc: Decodable {
    let webUrl: String
    let abstract: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case webUrl = "web_url"
        case abstract
    }

    init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        abstract = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .abstract)
        webUrl = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .webUrl)
    }

}
```

And I call `fetchData` in my `viewDidLoad`, then my array `var storyData = [Doc]()` is populated with the results:

```
    fetchData(url: jsonUrl) { (result: FetchResult<Status>) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let object): self.storyData = object.response.flatMap{$0.docs}
        print("Results \n\n\n\n \(object.response.flatMap{$0.docs})")
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure what to change here to get this to work. I've tried using quicktype.io to compare my code and I have my structs set up almost exactly the same way as it's generated there. This is what's generated on that site, for reference: https://app.quicktype.io?share=GGomMYH27NtkVpxXiAxB

I've checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179922/debugdescription-expected-to-decode-arrayany-but-found-a-dictionary-instead) and from the solution posted by @vadian I gather that, in my case, the JSON member `response` is a dictionary and `docs` is an array of dictionaries - however I'm confused because an array of dictionaries is still an array, right? Also based off of his solution, I'm decoding the initial struct `Status`, and then through that accessing the `response` and finally getting what I need in `docs`:

```
self.storyData = object.response.flatMap{$0.docs}
```

How else can I approach this to get rid of the error?

Comment: Making that change (and changing `self.storyData = object.response.flatMap{$0.docs}` to `self.storyData = object.response.docs` ) results in this error when trying to print the data: `keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "abstract", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "response", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "docs", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 2", intValue: 2)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"abstract\", intValue: nil) (\"abstract\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007348/expected-to-decode-arrayany-but-found-a-dictionary-instead)

Comment: The error is self explanatory, the response is a dictionary, not an array. the error above is that there was no 'abstract' in the JSON that was expected

Comment: Learn to **read** JSON. It's very easy. There are only two collection types (*array* `[]` and *dictionary* `{}`) and 4 value types. And the `Codable` error messages are one to the most descriptive messages ever.

Comment: If you look at what quicktype generated and compare it to your objects you'll see that you declared your response as `let response: [Response]` when it should be `let response: Response`

Comment: @vadian I've read the JSON and the error message and am still struggling to implement a solution, hence the question. I've read through guides and other SO answers but still can't figure it out in my particular case.

Comment: @dan I've tried making that change, see my first comment

Comment: OK, learn to **understand** there error messages. The `{` clearly indicates that `response` is a dictionary so remove the `[]` (`let response: Response`) and if there is ***No value associated*** make the struct member optional (`let abstract: String?`)

Comment: I've made that change and even making `abstract` and `webUrl` optional still results in the same error message as my first comment. Which is confusing because the error says `"No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"abstract\", intValue: nil) (\"abstract\").", underlyingError: nil))`, but looking at the JSON, there IS a value for abstract.

Comment: Delete the `init` method or use `decodeIfPresent` for `abstract`.

Comment: Alright that seems to have worked - can I ask why the `init` method was getting in the way?

Comment: In most cases you don't need the `init` method because it's synthesized by the protocol. If you are going to use it you have to use `decodeIfPresent` for the optional struct members.

Comment: Ok - I think you or another SO user suggested `init` in another answer when the JSON was empty for a specific piece of data, using something like `abstract = (try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .abstract)) ?? []`, or I guess in this case something like `abstract = (try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .abstract)) ?? ""`. But I'll refrain from using an initializer in future cases. Thanks as always for your help!